# Where to learn Quadruped Rigging from?

Tags: rigging

I am begginer animator, learning about rigging, animation, constraints etc. Did some humanoid rigs, got some logic, but now I want to learn Quadruped rigging for dog. Can't find any quality content for Blender. There are some tutorials for Maya, and it seems similiar but still there is a lot of differences. However, I find a lot of artworks with complete quadruped rigs, so I want to know what would be quality content for learning.